# XRay REST API says Custom-Field Non-valid Format

Tags: json, import, jira, jira-xray

Here is the request I make to import a test result into an XRay Test item in Jira.

```
curl -L 'https://jira.[xyz].com/rest/raven/2.0/import/execution' -H 'Authorization: Basic Z3V5bDoyNDIxQmxlaWdo' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=8A29ED3A4C045C60DACF236DAF8EDA9E; atlassian.xsrf.token=BFS8-LR8B-Z1EU-6YVL_f235c7a5028addccb3a41945753385105b205e1b_lin' -d '{
    "tests": [
        {
            "testKey": "NCS-55808",
            "start": "2023-03-09T07:43+23:95",
            "finish": "2023-03-09T07:43+24:95",
            "status": "PASS",
            "comment": "OK",
            "customfield_14000": {
                "id": 14000,
                "value": "Automation"
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

The result I get is:

```
{
    "error": "Error instantiating bean. Field(s) tests -> customfield_14000 do not follow the correct format."
}
```

`customfield_14000` is defined in our Jira instance as "Capacity Category".

I got the same result when trying "Capacity Category" instead of "customfield_14000".

#### What Else I Tried - Multipart

I also tried the `multipart` API.

`issueFields.json`:

```
{
    "project": {
        "id": "10006"
    },
    "fields": {
        "summary": "new test execution",
        "customfield_14000": [
            "Automation"
        ]
    }
}
```

Result was:

```
{
    "error": "Error assembling issue data: project is required"
}
```

And I did verify it is the correct ID.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "project": {
            "key": "NCS"
        },
        "summary": "new test execution",
        "customfield_14000": {
            "value": "Automation"
        }
    }
}
```